# How to convert HEX string to UInt16?

Tags: ios, swift, uint8t, uint, uint16

I have a HEX string d285 and I want to convert it UInt16, please guide me how I can convert it. I tried this

```
let buffer = UInt16("\(UInt8(text, radix: 16)!)")
return Data(bytes: (buffer?.bigEndian.toBytes)!)
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UInt16 has an [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint16/2925848-init) that takes a string and radix value. This can be used to create UInt16 from string.

```
let hexString = "d285"
let hexToInt = UInt16(hexString, radix: 16) // prints 53893
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let hexStr = "d285"
var byteArr = [UInt8]()
byteArr += hexStr.utf8  // Convert into byte array

let str = NSString(bytes: byteArr, length: byteArr.count, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
let number = UInt(str, radix: 16)!
```

> Hope this will help you